# Git workflow for example files based on master file within repository

Tags: git, file, github, copy

I forked a project using a main config file and several example config files. Now I would like to add my own example, based on a different one:

Repo

- config.h
- ExamplesFolder/

  - exampleconfig1.h
  - MyExampleConfig.h (based on exampleconfig1)

I'm non git genious but I know git does not track copies/moves/renames. 
So the question is: What is the correct workflow to create the new configfile, so that in case of a rebase/merge with an updated master branch, new commits to exampleconfig1.h are applied to MyExampleConfig.h too?